# Updating openssl on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, openssl

Can I replace my openssl 0.9.8o-4squeeze16 package with http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1h-3_amd64.deb without any problems/concers? I did a `apt-get update` but I did not get a higher version than 0.9.8o-4squeeze16. Is there anything I should think about before installing it with `apt-get install openssl_1.0.1h-3_amd64.deb` ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to run the squeeze release? "Wheezy" is the current stable release you understand, and has openssl version 1.0.1e. Check your /etc/apt/sources.list for references to squeeze if you just want the current stable release

Answer (score 1):

Debian squeeze is no longer current, so you can't expect recent versions of programs to be available for it. If you really need the `openssl` command line tool, you could recompile it, but do consider whether you really need that: there aren't that many new features. There are still [security updates](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) for squeeze, if that's what you're concerned about.

If you have a program that is compiled with version 1.0.x of the OpenSSL library, you can install a [`libssl1.0.0`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libssl1.0.0) package (alongside the `libssl0.9.8` package that comes with the distribution). There's no official binary, but downloading the source from wheezy or jessie and recompiling the package on a squeeze machine should work.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser - cant I just install the .deb with apt-get install? Or are there any incompatibilities?

Comment: @jonas In order to install with `apt-get install`, you'd have to find a source that provides this package for squeeze. There's no official source, there might be an unofficial one somewhere. If you compile manually, you can install with `dpkg -i`.

Comment: so `wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1h-3_amd64.deb` and `dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1h-3_amd64.deb` but I just want to know, if everything will work fine after upgrading openssl from 0.9.8.0-4 to the version (1.01h-3).

Comment: @jonas You'll need to install the `libssl1.0.0` package since the `openssl` tool uses the `libssl` library and unsurprisingly requires a matching version. Furthermore you'll need to recompile them (they're from the same source package, `openssl`) because the packages in jessie are compiled for a more recent C library than what you have on squeeze. Again, are you sure you need to install a very recent version of OpenSSL on such an old system?

Comment: Do *nod* try to mix binaries from different distribution versions. You'll wind up breaking lots of stuff.

Comment: @Gilles : is there any specific compilation guide..so that i can try set libssl and opensll to 1.0 version in my debian 6